# Negating a sentence

Tags: string, nlp, negation

I'm looking for algorithm or function to negate a sentence,
for example:
input: "The Belgian kid like chocolate"
output: "The Belgian kid doesn't like chocolate"
Does anyone knows an Algorithm or ML model to perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

Popular language models can be fine-tuned for this task. This might be a bit of an overkill, but I was personally very impressed by this example of few-shot learning teaching Google T5 model to negate a sentence with a reasonable success rate with just a dozen samples:

https://towardsdatascience.com/poor-mans-gpt-3-few-shot-text-generation-with-t5-transformer-51f1b01f843e

Notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1r4NYdk47vsayOELyIGMeoR9xGf7PYveE?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

For a **rule-based negation approach**, you can take a look at the **Python module [negate](https://github.com/dmlls/negate)**<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: I am the author of the module.</sup>